# Hiding the export to excel button from SharePoint 2013 Lists menu only

Tags: xml, excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I have created a export to excel button which works in Mac and Windows. Now i want to hide the existing Export to Excel button from Lists Ribbon (Only Lists not library).
I wrote the custom action xml but it doesn't remove anything.
here is my xml

```
<CustomAction
Id="RemoveRibbonButton"
Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
<CommandUIExtension>
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition
      Location="Ribbon.List.Actions.ExportToSpreadsheet-Large" />
  </CommandUIDefinitions>
</CommandUIExtension>
```

I appended this to the existing xml which adds the button. That one is working fine.
Any idea what is not working.

Answer (score 1):

problem solved
replace this in the xml
<Location="Ribbon.List.Actions.ExportToSpreadsheet" />